# Calling a C# DLL from PowerBuilder

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, powerbuilder

Okay, so I have a PowerBuilder app. Can I make a DLL file c# that opens a new thread to run a process in the background? and call this dll in my PowerBUilder app? is such thing possible?

Here is my sample code:

Class2.cs

```
    string vartest;
    public void testonly()
    {
        vartest = "TESTING ONLY";
    }

    public string threadtest()
    {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(testonly));
        workerThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        workerThread.Abort();
        return vartest;
    }
```

Here is where I call this DLL from my PowerBuilder app located in the open event of the window:

```
OLEObject myoleobject
myoleobject = CREATE OLEObject
myoleobject.connecttonewobject("Sample.Class2") 

string test
test = myoleobject.threadtest()
messagebox('', test)
```

However, I get an error in my PowerBuilder app that says "Error calling external function..." at the line where I initialize the "test" variable.

Comment: Have you tried asking Mr. Google first?

Comment: @L-Three yeah, sadly, PowerBuilder has minimal support community.

Comment: Not sure what you did, but there are numerous google results, for example: http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/03/03/Calling-NET-from-PowerBuilder.aspx.

Comment: I already know how to call a DLL from PowerBuilder. Forgot to mention that, sorry. My question is is it possible to start a new thread in that DLL when it is called?

Comment: Why not? Create a small POC to test it.

Comment: @L-Three check my edit, please. :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of PowerBuilder? Is this PowerBuilder Classic or .Net? Is it properly registered? Try testing from VBScript and see what happens.

The official forum is here:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/powerbuilder

Comment: Hello, I am using PB Classic 12.5. How do I check if it is properly registered? I am using regasm.exe like this "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> regasm <dll path>\<dll name.dll>" and it says "type registered successfully".

Answer (score 0):

- Have you checked the return value of ConnectToNewObject? Is it successful?
- Check the registry by searching for the class you are trying to connect to
- You can also use the GUID in ConnectToNewObject, can you find that GUID in the registry?
- Have you made the C# class ComVisible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. For reference, the details of the problem can be found in the OleRuntimeError object that is returned with the exception you ran into.  For example, try adding this try catch block to your code:

```
try
    test = myoleobject.threadtest()
catch (OleRuntimeError oleex)
    Messagebox("OleRuntimeError", oleex.description + "~n" + oleex.GetMessage())
catch (RuntimeError ex)
    Messagebox("RuntimeError",ex.GetMessage())
end try
```

This should show you the details about what happened in the OLE error, which you can then decide what you need to do to fix it.